# C# - Record Click Strokes into an array?

Tags: c#, click

How can I record click strokes and then put them into an array? Also does the window always need to be in focus for it to work? How can I avoid this.

Comment: What do you mean? Keeping track of the X/y of each click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement that this works without having a focused window is the more difficult one.  You need to use a low-level mouse hook with the SetWindowsHookEx() API function.  This requires P/Invoke, a good example is available in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).